# filtering array of custom view controllers for property?

Tags: ios, swift, filter, uiviewcontroller

I have an array of viewControllers, various sub classes not all the same VC. I want to filter the array containing them all to identify that which matches my chosen filter.

Issue being that as its a variety of different types of VC being processed as just 'ViewControllers 'i cant filter by a clear property.

Is there an approach where I can define a property that will be on all the viewControllers and then filter by it?

a thought was i could sublass VC and then subclass the subclass for each controller, that way i can cast them all to that type and check that parameter

Here is the code: However i want to swap 'title' for a custom property

```
contentViewControllers = contentControllers()

        if self.pushedTitle != nil && self.pushedID != nil, self.pushedPage != nil {
            if let i = contentViewControllers.index(where: { $0.title == self.pushedPage }) {
                return selectContentViewController(contentViewControllers[i])
            }
```

edit: update on VC init

```
let text = TextViewController(textView: TextView.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds), pageID: page.pageid, pageTitle: page.title)
                let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: text)
                contentList.append(navigationController)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to add a `protocol` like:

```
protocol PropertyProtocol {
    var customProperty: String { get }
}
```

Then make your view controllers conform to the `PropertyProtocol`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PropertyProtocol {
    var customProperty: String {
        return "My property for view Controller"
    }
...
}
```

Then you just do:

```
let i = contentViewControllers.index(where: { (viewController) -> Bool in
    if let viewController = viewController as? PropertyProtocol {
        return viewController.customProperty == pushedPage
    }
    return false
})
```

Of course, name your protocol to be more descriptive than in my case.

Since you already have a `TextViewController` subclass you can do:

```
let i = contentViewControllers.index(where: { (viewController) -> Bool in
    var vc = viewController
    if let navVC = viewController as? UINavigationController {
        vc = navVC.viewControllers.first!
    }

    if let textViewController = vc as? TextViewController {
        return textViewController.pageID == pushedPage
    }

    return false
})
```

Last option and the one maybe you should choose is add a new variable next to `contentList` - `var viewControllerIndexes = [String : Int]()` and then when you do:

```
contentList.append(navigationController)
viewControllerIndexList[page.pageid] = contentList.count - 1
```

Then when you need a index for a page ID you dont need to search but just do `let index = viewControllerIndexList["myPageID"]`

Comment: The issue here is that i dont know the property to set it in the class like that, i pass it in on initialisation, not hardcoded

Comment: @jackdm Then you can change the implementation to use a stored property

Comment: Can you show us how you do the initialization and then we can show how it could be done...

Comment: OP updated with example, so i call that and add to the array, so each custom VC type has its pageID assigned to its class variable, rather than a protocol. on reflection im adding navigation controllers and tabbarcontrollers to the array of viewcontrollers. rather than each of my specific viewcontrollers so perhaps i need to extend nav and tab controllers intead?

Comment: Inside `TextViewController` how is `pageID: page.pageid` stored? As a property called `pageID` in  `TextViewController`?

Comment: Also is `contentViewControllers` filled with `UINavigationController` that have rootViewController set to `TextViewController` or is it filled with `TextViewController`?

Comment: yea its stored in a var pageID: String and assigned on the init. its filled with UINavigationController which have various viewControllers as their roots, and 1 tabbarcontroller. No actual viewcontrollers, so i guess i need to filter by a property that the nav controller and tab bar controller can hold? unless i can access their root controllers properties

Comment: thanks for your update, how do i handle the situation where the contents of each nav controller in the view is actually a different type of viewController? i have TextViewController, DashViewController etc etc, all as roots of nav controllers. do i just use lots of if lets for each type?

Comment: And each one of theese has this `pageID` property?

Comment: yes each has pageID set from its init before we filter through, i tried your code and it does work correctly. Its just i need it scaling across a variety of VC subclasses rather than just Text. I assume i could make a generic subclass with a pageID property and cast all the navVC values to it and read the page ID there?

Comment: Read my update above...basically add a dictionary that maps your pageIDs with view controllers and then when you need any `viewController` for `pageID` you can get it easily

Comment: thanks makes sense, but i just need the position in the contentViewControllers array of the controller with that ID, not the controller its self

Comment: Updated the answer, so that instead of view controllers you are saving the current index...